# jQuery timeago not always working

Tags: jquery, timeago

i have this source, that write the time ago. (i use timeago plugin of jQuery)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});

function timeago(time) {
    isoTime = new Date();
    isoTime.setTime(time);
    return "<abbr class='timeago' title='"+isoTime.toISOString()+"'></abbr>";
}


function add() {
     $('#ex').append( timeago(time) );
}
</script>
```

when i try to call to `add()` function, its not always work.

*this is **works good**:*

```
<script>
add();
</script>
```

*but when i try to call it from a button, its **not work**:*

```
<button onclick='add()'>button</button>
```

---

i think its not work becouse this line `$("abbr.timeago").timeago();` could not read the new `<abbr>` that i add. (maybe it could read just the `<abbr>` that added before this line `$("abbr.timeago").timeago();` act)

someone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Are you defining `time` which is being passed to timeago() from within add()?

Comment: hi @HartSimha thanks for trying help! but yes, its not the problem.

Comment: If you are relying on clicking the button to insert the <abbr> element with class 'timeago' into the DOM, this element will not exist at the point where `$("abbr.timeago").timeago();` is executed... `$("abbr.timeago").timeago();` will be executed on page load, and therefore will not target any elements unless you already have an "abbr.timeago" on the page on page load

Comment: @HartSimha yeahh i understand that, do you have any creative idea  how could i solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I've just posted my suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the $(document).ready(..) block and instead define `add()` as follows:

```
function add() {
     $('#ex').append( $(timeago(time)).timeago() );
}
```

As a side note, it's probably best to avoid giving a global function the same name as a jQuery method being used here. `function timeago(..` could be `function newElFromTime(time)`

You might even modify it to return a jQuery object which you invoke the .timeago() method on instead of a plain HTML string:

```
function newTimeagoFromTime(time) {
    isoTime = new Date();
    isoTime.setTime(time);
    return $("<abbr class='timeago' title='"+isoTime.toISOString()+"'></abbr>").timeago();
}

function add() {
     $("#ex").append(newTimeagoFromTime(time));
}
```